# How to grant permissions to user for current schemas and schemas created in the future?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a Postgres database and a read-only user that I want to grant permissions to. I have two schemas currently but expect to make many more in the future. How do I grant select permissions to my read-only user so that they can read data from the tables that are currently created as well as tables that will be created in a new schema in the future?

I don't want to have to explicitly grant permissions for each new schema when they are created.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) without specifying any schema:

> The privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the current database) […]
>   If `IN SCHEMA` is omitted, the global default privileges are altered.

So this should do it:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR whoever_will_create_the_tables
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO the_readonly_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR whoever_will_create_the_schemas
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO the_readonly_user;
```

[Granting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-grant.html) the privilege on the tables that already are created needs a separate statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_1, schema_2 TO the_readonly_user;
```

Comment: Even after doing this I'm still getting an error: `ERROR: permission denied for schema`

Comment: Ah, I guess this needs a `GRANT USAGE` on the schemas as well.

Comment: After some more research, it looks like there are no default privileges for schemas.

Comment: @cdc1996 Looks like default privileges for schemas are supported since Postgres 10 but not before.